# Why am I getting an error 'Invalid table name', When i am trying to create another table with foreign key with the primray key of the first table

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

There is a parent table with the name of "SALESPERSON123" with primary key "SSN"

```
SQL> DESC SALESPERSON123;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 SSN                                       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(30)
 START_YR                                           NUMBER
 DEPT_NO                                            VARCHAR2(30)
```

I want to create another table "Trip" in which I want to make "SSN" the foreign key, but i am getting following error.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE TRIP
  2  (
  3  TRIP_ID VARCHAR2(30),
  4  SSN VARCHAR2(30),
  5  FROM_CITY VARCHAR2(30),
  6  TO_CITY VARCHAR2(30),
  7  DEP_DATE NUMBER,
  8  RETURN_DATE NUMBER,
  9  FOREIGN KEY (SSN) REFERENCES TO SALESPERSON123(SSN),
 10  PRIMARY KEY (TRIP_ID)
 11  );
FOREIGN KEY (SSN) REFERENCES TO SALESPERSON123(SSN),
                             *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

I tried to multiple time, by deleting and again creating the parent table but no there is no avail.

Comment: Use `FOREIGN KEY (SSN) REFERENCES SALESPERSON123(SSN)` ... there is no `ON` to be used here.  Voting to close as a typo question.

Comment: A very precise error message by the way: "invalid table name" and an asterix pointing to `TO` :-) If just messages were always that exact.

Comment: Is it Downvoters Day or what is happening here? Even if the mistake seems obvious to us, it wasn't to the OP, and they've described the problem well and have given all the information needed to help them.

Comment: For future debugging there's a difference between the "ORA-00903: invalid table name" you get here - which is because `TO` should not be there at all but as it is it's being seen as a table name, and is invalid as such because [it's a reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html) - and "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" which seems to be how you interpreted it. You were trying to fix the wrong problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `TO`. It must be:

```
FOREIGN KEY (SSN) REFERENCES SALESPERSON123(SSN),
```

instead of

```
FOREIGN KEY (SSN) REFERENCES TO SALESPERSON123(SSN),
```

Answer (score -2):

A foreign key is a way to enforce referential integrity within your Oracle database. A foreign key means that values in one table must also appear in another table.

The referenced table is called the parent table while the table with the foreign key is called the child table. The foreign key in the child table will generally reference a primary key in the parent table.

A foreign key can be defined in either a CREATE TABLE statement or an ALTER TABLE statement.

```
CREATE TABLE supplier
    ( supplier_id numeric(10) not null,
      supplier_name varchar2(50) not null,
      contact_name varchar2(50),
      CONSTRAINT supplier_pk PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE products
    ( product_id numeric(10) not null,
      supplier_id numeric(10) not null,
      CONSTRAINT fk_supplier
        FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id)
        REFERENCES supplier(supplier_id)

);
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original question being asked.